# Java: Async method invocation which returns different type data

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice

I want to execute 3 java methods and all of them return different type of data (say Class type). Is there a way I can run these 3 methods in parallel using `ExecutorService`? In this way `call()` method needs to return something in specific which spoils my idea of using it.

Let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried so far in your question.  Please read [ask] and then provide an [mcve]

Comment: If the return values have nothing in common you can return `Object`. Anyway, your code receiving the results will have to figure out what it has got

Answer (score 0):

The `call()` method usually returns something specific, that's why it's useful. You can create 3 different types of `Callables` and there's no problem.

```
Callable<A> c1 = () -> { return getA(); };
Callable<B> c2 = () -> { return getB(); };
Callable<C> c3 = () -> { return getC(); };

Future<A> f1 = executor.submit(c1);
Future<B> f2 = executor.submit(c2);
Future<C> f3 = executor.submit(c3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Executors accept Callable tasks, which are generic functional interfaces designed to return arbitrary types.

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executorService.submit(() -> "Hello");
    executorService.submit(() -> new BigDecimal("1.1"));
    executorService.submit(() -> new ArrayList());
```

submit() returns a Future, a generic holder for the computation result, which will have the same generic type as the data returned by your Callable.

```
    Future<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> "Hello");
```

To access the result, simply call get() :

```
    String result = future.get();
```